# Spark with AWS Elastic Search integration - Getting - Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only' error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, amazon-emr, aws-elasticsearch

Create AWS Elastic search with public access and try to push dataframe into ES from my local , i am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
```

The same workflow i tried in EMR and getting the same exception. What would be reason is blocking ? any idea
Note : Configured right ES instance jar in maven and below are my code for references

```
userDF.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
    .option("es.mapping.id", "id")
    .option("spark.es.index.auto.create", "true")
    .option("spark.es.nodes", "https://emrtoser-searchdomain-7uertdoiicyf42hw3rtyhqc7y.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com") 
    .option("spark.es.batch.size.entries", "1000")  
    .option("spark.es.net.http.auth.user", "xxxx")
   .option("spark.es.net.http.auth.pass", "XXXxxx123#") 
    
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .save("user/data")
```

Comment: Any suggestion team?